# Android ListView Item Selected Event

Tags: android, listview, dictionary, infowindow

I am trying to pop out an info window on the marker based on the item selected from listview. So basically when the listview item was selected, it will execute the createCallOutView():

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                int position, long id) {

            float x = Float.parseFloat(_eventlist.get(position).getEventX());
            float y = Float.parseFloat(_eventlist.get(position).getEventY());

            ENeighbourhoodActivity.callout.hide();
            int[] graphicIDs = ENeighbourhoodActivity.graphicsLayer.getGraphicIDs(x, y, 25);
            if (graphicIDs != null && graphicIDs.length > 0) {
                Graphic gr = ENeighbourhoodActivity.graphicsLayer.getGraphic(graphicIDs[0]);
                Point location = (Point) gr.getGeometry();
                ENeighbourhoodActivity.callout.setOffset(0, -10);
                ENeighbourhoodActivity.callout.show(location, EventInfoWindow.createCalloutView(
                        gr, context, userID));
            } 
            getActivity().finish();

        }
    });
```

And in my createCallOutView(), it just basically displaying displaying the details of events. However, with theses codes, when the listview item was selected, the screen just freeze and after a while it just shows the application is not responding message and close the activity.

Any ideas? There is no error messages at all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be your code takes more time in Graphics part. Pt the in another thread so that main thread is not stopped.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
            int position, long id) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          float x = Float.parseFloat(_eventlist.get(position).getEventX());
          float y = Float.parseFloat(_eventlist.get(position).getEventY());

          ENeighbourhoodActivity.callout.hide();
          int[] graphicIDs = ENeighbourhoodActivity.graphicsLayer.getGraphicIDs(x, y, 25);
         if (graphicIDs != null && graphicIDs.length > 0) {
            Graphic gr = ENeighbourhoodActivity.graphicsLayer.getGraphic(graphicIDs[0]);
            Point location = (Point) gr.getGeometry();
            ENeighbourhoodActivity.callout.setOffset(0, -10);
            ENeighbourhoodActivity.callout.show(location, EventInfoWindow.createCalloutView(
                    gr, context, userID));

         } 
         getActivity().finish();
        }
        }).start();


    }
});
```

Dont forget to use **runOnUiThread** when you want to update the UI

Comment: But I got syntax error, misplaced construct at the new Thread there. And what about the runOnUiThread?

Comment: Edited the answer try it out

Comment: But it does not show the info window which is supposed to be there when I call the createCallOutView(). It just close the activity itself :(

Comment: Nope, it does not work. It returned to the same problem which is the screen just freeze and nothing happened as previously after your second edits.

Comment: Any ideas? Because this createCallOutView() will be called when map on single tap and it works well with that but not this.

Comment: Try debugging the threads using DDMS and find which code is causing ANR

Comment: Anyway, thanks! I figured out another ways to do this.